# Member 'LockscreenNotification.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with an type name instead

Tags: c#

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = (Application.Current as App).RootFrame;
rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
rootFrame.Unobscured += Unobscured;
```

i am writing this code in app() constructor of app class but getting an error -
Member 'LockscreenNotification.App.RootFrame.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with an type name instead.

Comment: That's a very clear error message. Did you do as it says?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I fixed doing this:

```
PhoneApplicationFrame rootFrame = App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
if (rootFrame != null)
{
    rootFrame.Obscured += OnObscured;
    rootFrame.Unobscured += OnUnobscured;
}
```